# SQL Server - Select distinct Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have a tblA where I have a few thousand clients. I'm trying to write a query that would show me clients that have more than one record of a certain type. This is what my table looks like.

```
ClientID          TypeB
123               1
145               1
123               2
199               1
199               2
145               2
123               1
```

So as you can see here (this is not a complete table, but this is only relevant). Each client is supposed to only have one record for TypeB=1 and TypeB=2. Some clients however(123) has more than one record for TypeB=1. I'm trying to find all clients that have more than one record of Type=1.

Desired end result:

```
ClientID           TypeB
123                1
123                1
```

This is what I've been trying to do

```
 select distinct(clientid), TypeB
 from tblA 
 where TypeB=1
 having count(TypeB)>1
 group by clientid
```

Comment: I know you've already accepted an answer but I'll note that you really only needed to reverse the `having` and `group by` in your query. The grouping on `TypeB` was not a necessary part of the solution.

Comment: @shawnt00 - i noticed that it was close enough. But at times i try to build a query and i keep getting the error in sql server which is just annoying but I was close. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you need something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientID), ClientID, TypeB
FROM tblA
WHERE TypeB = 1
GROUP BY ClientID, TypeB
HAVING COUNT(ClientID) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT a.clientid, 
       a.typeb 
FROM   tblA  a 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   tblA  b 
        WHERE  b.clientid = a.clientid 
               AND b.typeb = 1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

See if it works in sql server:

```
select *
from client
qualify sum()over(partition by clientId, typeB)>1
```

other easy way is

```
select *
from client
where clientId in 
(select clientId 
from client
having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
;with cte as (
select clientid, typeb, row_number() over(partition by clientid, typeb order by clientid) as rn
from yourtable ) select clientid, typeb from cte where rn > 1
```